Components of velocity in projectile motion
I came across this question in my physics textbook (Gr12) and I was hoping someone could explain the solution to me

A ball is thrown horizontally off a building at $8.2\,\text{m}/\text{s}$. At a point $P$, the ball is moving $60°$ to the horizontal. Show that the ball's vertical velocity at $P$ is $14.2\,\text{m}/\text{s}$.

I did manage to come across a solution to the problem, that being $14.2 = 8.2\tan 60°$. But I don't understand why the ratio between the ball's vertical velocity to its horizontal velocity is used here.

The horizontal velocity does not change during the fall. So the total velocity can be inferred from the angle given.
